# OrientDB query friend of friends with more information and filtering

Tags: orientdb

**Introduction:**

Hi,

I have a question regarding how to create an OrientDB query. The query should get all the vertices of the friends of friends (this is equivalent to the second level relationship) + the bridge between the 2. After that, the query should filter the records after an edge property.

I am running OrientDB 1.7.4.

**Schema example:**

Let's take an example, taking the following schema:

-> User is a Vertex, with property id (int)

-> Knows is an Edge, with property type (string) (let's say this property has a few values: friend, family, etc.)

The relations I am looking for are like this:

```
User <--knows--> User <--knows--> User
(1)              (2)              (3)
```

I need all relations, doesn't matter what direction they have (even if the direction is important for other queries).

To get all Users (User3) of second degree, a query like this will suffice:

```
select expand( set(both().both()) ) from <rid>
```

**Questions:**

Now, I have 2 main problems / questions I can't figure them out:

1. If the query above return a list of records from the class User (User3), how can I get the record as User (User3) AND the User (or the property id) from the user in the middle of the relation (see above: User2)
2. How can I filter the query to traverse (or select) only through edges that have a certain property. To be more specific I want the second query to find the Users that are from question 1 but that are friend of friends: `User <--knows(method='friend')--> User <--knows(method='friend')--> User`.

Comment: This `select bothE('knows')[method='friend'] from User` gives you edges with method 'friend'. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Hi, take your for the answer. This helps, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. This way I can get the edges, but not vertices. I need my output to be of class User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vitorenesduarte suggested, I found the answer. Yes I should look for edges, filter the edges, than take out the vertices from the edges, like following:

```
select expand( unionAll(inE('knows')[method='friend'].out, outE('knows')[method='friend'].in ) from <rid>
```

The problem with this query is that I think it could be optimized if OrientDB would have a function to take both way vertices from edges, something like this:

```
bothE('knows')[method='friend'].both
```

But the `.both` function doesn't exist (at least in the version I use, which is 1.7.4). If anyone knows something about this, please leave a comment.

Comment: I believe that __out__ here: `inE('knows')[method='friend'].out` is a property, not a function. And that's why .both won't work.

Comment: you can use bothV() as explained on my answer above

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
TREVERSE * FROM (SELECT FROM User WHERE id == 1)
WHILE (@class == 'User') OR (@class == 'Knows' AND method == 'friend')
```

This will give you all vertices and edges starting from vertex with id = 1.

If you want to stop at the 2nd level, then

```
TREVERSE * FROM (SELECT FROM User WHERE id == 1)
WHILE (@class == 'User') OR (@class == 'Knows' AND method == 'friend')
MAXDEPTH 2
```

If you only want to have vertices:

```
SELECT FROM (
    TREVERSE * FROM (SELECT FROM User WHERE id == 1)
    WHILE (@class == 'User') OR (@class == 'Knows' AND method == 'friend')
    MAXDEPTH 2
)
WHERE @class == 'User '
```

If you happen to need to know the path from the initial person to the last one, and all the possible paths from id = 1 up to the 2nd level.

```
SELECT $path FROM (
        TREVERSE * FROM (SELECT FROM User WHERE id == 1)
        WHILE (@class == 'User') OR (@class == 'Knows' AND method == 'friend')
        MAXDEPTH 2
    )
```

But if you have a fixed depth is better to do it with select, try this:

```
SELECT bothE('Knows')[method='friend'].bothV() FROM User WHERE id = 1
```